# calculated column in MS Access table can be edited?

Tags: ms-access

I created a table like that

```
  ID   |TraName |  income   | TrainerRatio%| TrainerMoney  | 
  1    |  gym   |    100    |     50       |  50   |
  2    |  spa   |    150    |     60       |  90   |
  3    |Kung fu |    140    |     40       |  56   |
  4    | Karate |    120    |     30       |  36   |
  5    | ADDnew |    ??     |     ??       |  ??   |
```

I created calculated column `TrainerRatio%`

```
IIf(TraName=gym,TrainerRatio=50,IIF(TraName=spa,TrainerRatio=60))
```

and so on, as i can't write switch in table i don't know why

And created calculated column `Trainermoney`

```
=(income*TrainerRatio%/100)
```

if i add new traing , TrainerRatio% will be 0 , how can i edit it?

Comment: Calculated columns' value should not be edited, this is why they are calculated. You need to update the calculation, if it is not up to your requirements. However, in this particular instance I do not understand why is TrainerRatio column a calculated one, since you are providing a list of values only. If you can have multiple records with the same traname, then consider having a separate table with traname and trainerratio and get the values from there via `dlookup()` in a calculated colum.

Comment: how can i use dlookup() ?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DLookup-Function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937